# Why don't the Waves Maxx speaker effects work in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, sound, soundcard

I have a new machine that comes with JBL 2.1 Speakers with Waves Maxx Audio 3.  On Windows it sounds perfect, though in Ubuntu 12.04 I get cheap/sound with simple mp3 files.  I have tried a few things on different blogs but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC665 Analog [ALC665 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC665 Digital [ALC665 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: N700 [Logitech Speaker Lapdesk N700], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I have same system . but its working flawlessly. What is that card 1, its not there in my system..  Check sound settings and see which card is being as output

Answer (score 2):

Things may sound "better" in Windows because of the *Waves MaxxAudio 3* package, which is a software sound-enhancer that can "improve" bass, etc on relatively tiny laptop speakers. It uses [psychoacoustics](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPsychoacoustics&ei=qMzmT4WzF8bo2AWYsdHZCQ&usg=AFQjCNGND2CAso_JRLITeJF6YapDbmbFwA&sig2=9ptaEaqgeI4UxMUAhwZMOA) to do this, i.e. it manipulates the sound so that the human brain is tricked into making it sound "better".

**Note that the Waves drivers are *Windows-only***, so you won't get these effects in Ubuntu. *Waves* claims a ["Linux Edition"](http://www.waves.com/newsletters/june09/pb/MaxxAudio_LE.pdf) is available, so please contact your manufacturer -- I assume Dell -- to get that.

> [**Source:**](http://www.maxx.com/content.aspx?id=739) *MaxxAudio 3 is compatible with Microsoft Windows Vista and Windows 7.
>
>   For Linux-based systems, Waves has introduced MaxxAudio LE.
>
>   Waves CE works with leading codec manufacturers to ensure simple, seamless integration.*