# Dell Vostro 3468 needs maxx audio pro driver

Tags: drivers, sound, windows, dell

Audio isn't working properly; when using headphones, the audio quality is terrible in Ubuntu on a Dell [Vostro 3468](https://www.dell.com/support/article/ag/en/agbsdt1/sln302999/dell-vostro-14-3468-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide?lang=en). How may I get the maxxaudio pro driver for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155257/why-dont-the-waves-maxx-speaker-effects-work-in-ubuntu), the Maxxaudio LE drivers are for Linux, not the Maxxaudio Pro, which are for Windows, and will not work in Linux.  The Maxxaudio drivers provide a marked improvement of sound quality per that same post.

The LE drivers have been discontinued. The [link to the publisher is broken](http://www.maxx.com/content.aspx?id=739), a search at the [publisher's website revealed nothing](https://www.waves.com/support/search?searchtext=linux&searchmode=anywordorsynonyms), and [a search at the Dell site for your model revealed no drivers available](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-14-3468-laptop/drivers).

Comment: You don't need Maxx. Sound quality should be more than adequate in Ubuntu so it sounds like you may have an audio issue, Need to see output for `sudo lshw -C multimedia` and `aplay -l`. Also what application are you using to play audio?

Comment: Sound quality is not good on Ubuntu. and without maxx audio. I cant enjoy my bass on headphone like windows